# Can I embed a ComboBox and a simple Button into a StatusStrip in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, statusstrip

By default ComboBox and Button elements are not among those offered to add into a StatusStrip by WinForms designer (while DropDownButton and SplitButton are). Is there a way to add them there? As far as I've heard any control can be embedded there, but how?

Comment: Why are not you satisfied with the proposed ones?

Comment: Proposed what? There is no ComboBox analogue offered for embedding into StatusStrip (a ComboBox is a drop-down list with a user-editable text field - I need a user to be able to enter text there), neither is TextBox (which I could use instead by combining it with a DropDownButton).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can implement easily inheriting from [`ToolStripControlHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k5etstz.aspx):

```
[ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.MenuStrip |
                                       ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.ContextMenuStrip | 
                                       ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.StatusStrip)]
    public class ComboStripItem : ToolStripControlHost
    {
        private ComboBox combo;

        public ComboStripItem()
            : base(new ComboBox())
        {
            this.combo = this.Control as ComboBox;
        }

        // Add properties, events etc. you want to expose...
    }
```

---

After rebuilding your solution you will able to see the item even in the designer:

[image: ComboStripItem in forms designer]

**P.S.**
this item will be usable also in `ContextMenuStrip` and in `MenuStrip`.

**EDIT:**

To set a custom icon use [`ToolboxBitmapAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.toolboxbitmapattribute.aspx).

However, I noticed that actually there's a built-in combobox toolstrip item called `ToolStripComboBox`.
It has just no designer visibility for the StatusStrip , but it can be easily added to a StatusStrip by code, or, if you prefer, you can extend it giving the complete visibility:

```
 [ToolboxBitmapAttribute("image path or use another overload..."),
  ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.MenuStrip |
                                   ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.ContextMenuStrip |
                                   ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.StatusStrip)]
 public class ComboBoxItem : ToolStripComboBox
 {
 }
```

Comment: Damn - this is golded. Been stumbling around in this for a few days and those attribute tags are a godsend!

Answer (score 22):

More easily, you can cut a ToolStripComboBox created via the menu in a ToolStrip and paste it in the StatusStrip.
No lines of code written... and it works ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a **simple button** to your `StatusStrip`, you can do so using the Designer.

First, add a `DropDownButton`. Then, in the `DropDownButton` properties window, set the `ShowDropDownArrow` property to `False`.

Repeat for each additional simple button that you want to show in your `StatusStrip`.